# let declarations require an initializer expression

Tags: ios, constants, swift, let

I'm reading The Swift Programming Language, in the Simple Values section

> “Use let to make a constant and var to make a variable. The value of a
>   constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time, but you must assign
>   it a value exactly once”

So I think I can do this

```
let aConstant:Int
aConstant = 5
```

But I get **let declarations require an initializer expression** !!

Why is that ? What does they mean by "The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time" ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [Swift Language Reference](https://itun.es/ch/jEUH0.l):

> When a constant is declared at global scope, it must be initialized with a value.

You can only defer initialization of a constant in classes/structs, where you can choose to initialize it in the initializer of the class/struct.

The meaning of "The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time" refers to the value of the constant. In C/Objective-C a global constant needs to be assigned a value that can be computed by the compiler (usually a literal like `10` or `@"Hello"`). The following would not be allowed in Objective-C:

```
static const int foo = 10; // OK
static const int bar = calculate_bar(); // Error: Initializer element is not a compile-time constant
```

In Swift you don't have this restriction:

```
let foo = 10 // OK
let bar = calculateBar(); // OK
```

**Edit:**

The following statement in the original answer is not correct:

> You can only defer initialization of a constant in classes/structs, where you can choose to initialize it in the initializer of the class/struct.

The only place where you cannot defer is in *global scope* (i.e. top level `let` expressions). While it's true that you can defer initialization in a class/struct, that's not the only place. The following is also legal for example:

```
func foo() {
    let bar: Int
    bar = 1 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A constant does not need to be known at compile, but it must have a value after initialization:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
    let aConstant: Integer; // no value

    init()  {
        aConstant = 4; // must have a value before calling super
        super.init();
    }
}
```

This allows you to set the constant to a value after it is declared and potentially unknown at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

the `let` keyword, by definition, defines a `constant`.

Thus, you can't modify it once its been set.

Since thats the case, they need to be initialized when they are declared!

The solution here is to do either:

```
let aConstant = 5
```

or change it to a `var`

```
var aNonConstant:Int
aNonConstant = 5
```

Comment: how about "The value of a constant doesn’t need to be known at compile time" ?

Comment: No it doesn't, you can do `let aConstant = functionThatGeneratesARandomNumber()`, but its still a constant after that point and you can't re-assign it.

Comment: Also, constants in Swift aren't restricted to literals such as `Int`. You can have a constant thats an object created at run-time. The only thing you have to remember is that it cannot be re-assigned after its defined (constant!)

Comment: Jack, you are wrong. constants DO NOT need to be initialized when they are declared. They need to be initialized once, but not necessarily on the same line that they are declared.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for Swift 2:

You can write constants as follows:

```
let aConstant:Int
aConstant = 5
```

Setting the type this way means: "This will be constant and it will have value when you need it". Notice that you cannot use the constant before setting value to it, there is a compile time error:

> Constant 'aConstant' used before being initialized

Furthermore you can set value to `aConstant` only once. If you try to set value for second time, there is compile time error:

> Immutable value 'aConstant' may only be initialized once

Anyway you cannot do this for global constants, there is compile time error:

> Global 'let' declaration requires an initializer expression